# how to access multiple objects by name?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried but couldn't... My code is as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i == oList.Count; i++)
{
    GameObject.Find(oList[a]).GetComponent<Image>().color = GreenCol;
    a++;
}
```

i am getting this error:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException (System.ExceptionArgument argument, System.ExceptionResource resource) (at <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0)
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException () (at <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0)
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].get_Item (System.Int32 index) (at <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0)
LevelManager.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/LevelManager.cs:27)
```

im use unity game engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you iterate over an Array in a for-loop you should also use the i variable you declared in the loop.

Also as the oList.Count returns the size of the array, you start always at 0 as the first Position. So the condition to leave the loop should bei `i < oList.Count` as `oList.Count -1` is the last Item in your Array.

If your array contains the names of the objects as strings, your code should look like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < oList.Count; i++)
{
    GameObject.Find(oList[i]).GetComponent<Image>().color = GreenCol;
}
```

If the array contains the GameObjects directly your code should look like in Eduard Hasanaj's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is wrong there. Why do you need variable a?
I suggest you to try and learn some of programming concepts.
Here it is the reworked code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < oList.Count; i++)
{
    oList[a].GetComponent<Image>().color = GreenCol;
}
```